# beautiful soup DIV parse based on H2

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to parse a very extensive HTML document which looks something like:

```
<br>
<div class="reportsubsection n" ><br>
    <h2> 1.4 Test </h2><br>
    <p> insert text here </p ><br>
    <table> crazy table thing here < /table ><br>
</div>
<div class="reportsubsection n"><br>
    <h2> 1.4 Finding < /h2 ><br>
    <p> insert text here < /p ><br>
    <table> crazy table thing here < /table><br>
</div>
```

I need to parse out the second `div` based on `h2` having the text "Finding". I was able to break out all `div` tags with:

```
divTag = soup.find("div", {"id": "reportsubsection"})
```

but didn't know how to dwindle it down from there. Based on other posts I found, I was able to find the specific text "part 2 but I need to be able to print the whole `div` section it is contained in.
Basically if `div` has `class=reportsubsection` and `h2` has word "Finding" in it, print the whole 'div`.

I tried the below based on some other posts I found but it didn't return any results.

```
divTag = soup.find("div", {"id": "reportsubsection"})
for reportsubsection in soup.select('div#reportsubsection #reportsubsection'):
if not reportsubsection.findAll('h2', text=re.compile('Finding')):
continue
print divTag
```

Comment: This doesn't return any results because that `soup.select` isn't going to match anything. Neither will the `find`, but that doesn't matter, because you aren't going to get to the point that you use it. Also, even if both of those actually worked, you'd just print the first `div` over and over, because you're printing the result of a `find` on the top level, not each `reportsubsection`.

Comment: Anyway, if you really were able to break out all of the div tags from that table, it wasn't with the code you showed, which makes it pretty hard to debug the code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `div` element with `id` set to 'reportsubsection'. But in your HTML, it is the `div`'s `class` property that has the value 'reportsubsection'.

Try this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> data = '''<div class="reportsubsection n" ><br>
... <h2> 1.4 Test </h2><br>
... <p> insert text here </p><br>
... <table> crazy table thing here </table><br>
... </div>
... <div class="reportsubsection n"><br>
... <h2> 1.4 Finding </h2><br>
... <p> insert text here </p><br>
... <table> crazy table thing here </table><br>
... </div>'''

>>> soup = bs(data)
>>> div_tag = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "reportsubsection n"})
>>> for tag in div_tag:
...     if 'Finding' in tag.h2.text:
...             print tag.text
...

 1.4 Finding
 insert text here
 crazy table thing here
```

Comment: He wants to print out the entire `div`, not just the text of the `h2`. So change that last line to `print div_tag`. But otherwise, good explanation of the problem with his code and how to do it right.

Comment: @abarnert I think you have not seen my updated answer :)

Comment: That throws an error when i try to run it<br>                             if 'Finding' in tag.h2.text:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @shaktimaan: Ah, I see. The new names are a bit confusing; `div_tag` now means the list of all `div` tags, while `tag` means each tag. But it does the right thing.

Comment: @abarnert Please consider accepting the answer if it helped resolve your issue. Thanks.